# Python Multiclient Multithreaded server using sockets

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, client-server, python-multithreading

I am trying to create a simple multi-client server architecture using socket programming on Python 3.5.2. This is my *first experience* with creating a server-client program. It is a Quiz program where each question is asked to the client through a browser using HTML files and the answer is sent back to the server to calculate the clients points. In order to connect the clients to the web server where the HTML files and client results are hosted, I am using an intermediate server to act as a bridge between the clients and the web server. You can see the diagram below for clarity:

[image]

I am using very simple HTML files for the questions such as:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Quiz</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Question 1</h1>
    <p>Which of the followings is the 45th elect president of the United States?

    <form action="/Question_2.html" method="post">
        <input type="radio" name="answer" value="trump">Donald J. Trump<br>
        <input type="radio" name="answer" value="clinton">Hillary Clinton<br>
        <input type="radio" name="answer" value="obama">Barrack Obama
        <br><br>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>


</body>

</html>
```

When the client chooses an answer and submits is, the answer is sent to the web server and the next question is shown on the same browser tab. Now, the problem here is that everytime a new browser window is opened for a new question, naturally a new socket is created and connected to the multiplexing server. The code below is from MultiplexingServer.py:

```
MultiplexingServerName = 'localhost'
MultiplexingServerPort=12000

MultiplexingServerSocket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
MultiplexingServerSocket.bind((MultiplexingServerName, MultiplexingServerPort))
MultiplexingServerSocket.listen(1)
while True:

    print ('Ready to serve on port' ,MultiplexingServerPort)

    ConnectionSocket, address =  MultiplexingServerSocket.accept()
```

For example, when I open up a browser and enter the URL "http://localhost:12000/Question_1.html" ,  I am connected without problems, I can proceed to the next questions and the answers are sent to the web server. However, since a new page means a new socket and address, I am getting an output on the web server such as:

```
Message recieved from multiplexer server: 2,trump,127.0.0.1:58594
Given answer: trump
Message recieved from multiplexer server: 3,staryu,127.0.0.1:58596
Given answer: staryu
Message recieved from multiplexer server: 4,oak,127.0.0.1:58598
Given answer: oak
Message recieved from multiplexer server: 5,rengar,127.0.0.1:58600
Given answer: rengar
```

How am I to differentiate that these answers were given from the same person since new sockets are created and their address is changing for each new question(page)? What kind of a work-around can I use?

Comment: why are you using a different port every time? all connections should be made using the same port; imagine that your web browser would use a range of ports for all http requests instead of just port 80

Comment: Actually it is not the servers ports that are changing, web server and multiplexer server are always using the same port of course. The problem here is that everytime a new page is opened, a new socket is created to handle the GET/POST requests of that page, and since different sockets have different addresses, I am unable to track whether or not the answers to the questions are given by the same person. The addresses such as 127.0.0.1:58594 on the output of the web server are the addresses of used sockets.

Comment: I'm starting to question the purpose of that multiplexing server in the middle...but eve with it you should have the ip address of each of the client connection coming in to the multiplexing server...and that sounds like what you are looking for.